# How can i save image as a RelativeLayout

Tags: android

How to save an relative layout as an bitmap image....?
on run time I am adding images to relative layout.. then how to save it as an Bitmap Image.

I have no Idea on this concept... Please suggest the solutions for this.

Thank You.

Comment: take snapshot and save it as bitmap image and store as u like as image in sdcard

Comment: Hi SubbaReddy... thanks for ur reply....

Comment: u got the bit map and store image in sdcard??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/rlid"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Then in your activity use this code:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.rlid);
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
File file = new File("/sdcard/" + yourimagename + ".png");
try {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
    ostream.close();
    content.invalidate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but there is an error on file.createNewFile();

Comment: @MMakati what is the error?

Comment: It goes to catch block. 

"java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: @MMakati you need to add permission in manifest file

Comment: can you help me how to add permission?

Comment: @MMakati    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` add this is manifest file and this is harcoded `"/sdcard/"+yourimagename+".png"` instead use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and use `File.separator`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39703/discussion-between-mmakati-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
put one button in relative layout and then do this process the image stored in sdcard

```
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            view.buildDrawingCache();
            bm = view.getDrawingCache();

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/_images");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
            file = new File(myDir, fname);

            Log.i(TAG, "" + file);

            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: mapview.... whats this variable..?

Comment: exception .... in  bm = mapview.getDrawingCache(); line..

Comment: thats not mapview replace it with view

Comment: i edited the above code just watch it.....

Comment: Still not working.. Actually, my application is ..               have to select the stickers(images) from list view and add it to main image. And I have to edit (zoom,rotate,move and delete) the stickers.. that are added to main. and I have to save the main image in sd ..... DOne R&D but no solution I found.... If you are having knowledge on this concept... please help- me.... I am facing this issue from last 10 days..... still doing R&D....

Comment: Ya... facing difficulty.. trying trying....