# How to save whole list view as image in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap

There are few thread about save layout as image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117085/how-to-save-the-layout-view-as-image-or-pdf-to-sd-card-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986019/how-to-save-relative-layout-as-a-image).
What if I have a list view, and it is impossible to make them display on one screen.

Comment: Are the height of each item fixed or they can change?

Comment: This helps maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742343/android-get-screenshot-of-all-listview-items

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

First enable the drawing cache in your `ListView`

```
vListView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Then adjust the size of the `ListView` to make every item visible.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)  vListView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = (int) (mAdapter.getItemCount() * getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.max_item_height));
vListView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Finally you can use either a callback or do a postDelayed with a Handler and get the bitmap.

```
vListView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                drawingCache = vListView.getDrawingCache();
            }
        });
```

Let me know if it did help you.

BTW Remember that in Android Studio, in debug mode, you can check the bitmap variables contents.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it in hierarchy or it won't compute its layout. But no one says you have to actually show it on screen - create layout in which you can place ListView outside of screen bounds and use drawing cache to construct widget image.